# How to find all the phone number matches written in different formats using MongoDB Compass?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

I need to find phones by the field in which they are stored in different formats:

1. 1-234-567-89-10
2. 1 (234) 567-89-10
3. 1 234 567 89 10
4. 12345678910

I tried to solve it this way, but it didn't work.
`{ $replaceOne: { input: phone_field, find: "[^0-9]+", replacement: "" } : {$regex : "12345678910"}}`

Answer (score 0):

It is best if you keep your phone number field in one format , for example you can remove any other characters and keep only the number in the entire collection as follow:

```
db.collection.update({},
[
{
 "$set": {
  "phone": {
    "$reduce": {
      "input": {
        "$regexFindAll": {
          "input": "$phone",
          "regex": "\\d+"
        }
      },
      "initialValue": "",
      "in": {
        "$concat": [
          "$$value",
          "$$this.match"
        ]
      }
     }
   }
  }
  }
  ],
  {
     multi: true
  })
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/FO5aJtfdvDR)

And later you can search via $regex as follow:

```
db.collection.find({
 "$expr": {
  "$regexMatch": {
    "input": "$phone",
    "regex": "123"
  }
 }
})
```

[Playground2](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6G4kpffB_cR)